# Secuencial triggers mysql is already used by statatement

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

i'm working on a proyect in mysql and i can't made things work between 2 triggers, what i'm trying to do is

1)
Create a trigger that after inserting values ​​in a table update the data of another table, working

2)
Create a trigger that after updating the aforementioned table, delete the row that detonated the first trigger, not working

I searched the documentation, examples, tutorials, goolge and of course in different posts of the site, but I have not found anything that can guide me or help to solve my problem :(

For the moment i have this

1)

```
CREATE TRIGGER update1 BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW 
UPDATE table2 SET table2.value = table2.value + 
NEW.value WHERE ac_id = NEW.acc_id
```

2)

```
CREATE TRIGGER `delete` AFTER UPDATE ON table2
FOR EACH ROW DELETE FROM table1 WHERE table1.acco_id =
NEW.acc_id
```

Individually both work, but if I make an insert in table1 the following message appears

Can't update table 'table1' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

sorry for my bad English, any help will be highly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure there is a *question* here that can be answered. If the question is "Is this expected behavior?", then answer is "yes, this is a well documented restriction". If the question is "Is there a workaround?", the answer to that is "Not in the context of a single SQL INSERT statement, no, there isn't a workaround." It would be possible to perform the operations with two (or more) separate statements.

Comment: @spencer7593 The biggest limitation is that the data comes from a web page to which I do not have access, that is why a stored procedure can not be implemented, and according to what you say, is it possible to implement this in some other way?

Comment: Your `INSERT` statement fires two triggers. They perform actions between their two tables. MySQL stops you from doing this because it can lead to an infinite loop. What Spencer said was that you can't do this using 1 query (the `INSERT` one that starts the whole thing). You can't fix it because nothing is broken, MySQL stops you from shooting your foot. You need to come up with a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

The observed error message:

`ERROR 2442 (HY000) Can't update table '%s' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`

is expected behavior. The triggers shown in the question violate a documented restriction:

> A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

---

To focus that on the specific triggers shown in the question, in the context of a trigger fired by an insert into table1, it is *not possible* to delete rows from table1.  There is no workaround to this restriction.

To "solve this problem" means to step back from the current design, and come up with a different design which achieves the objectives.